# java class tester Issue

Tags: java, oop

I have created a student class that i need to create a tester file for, the file compiles however i get an error when i "java Student".
this error is :

```
TheRealFawcett:Lab8 therealfawcett$ java Student
Error: Main method not found in class Student, 
please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend 
javafx.application.Application
TheRealFawcett:Lab8 therealfawcett$
```

does anyone know why this happens? and what i would have to do to to fix it.

the code below is my original "Student" class file

This is my Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Student {
    private static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student("Charles");
    }

    private String forName;
    private String surName;
    private String studentID;
    private String degreeScheme;

    //This is the Constructor of the 
    public Student(String name) {
        this.forName = forName;
    }

    //Assign the surname of the student 
    public void stuSurname(String stuSurname) {
        surName = stuSurname;
    }

    //Assign the student ID to the student
    public void stuID(String stuID) {
        studentID = stuID;
    }

    //Assign the Degree of the Student
    public void stuDegree(String stuDegree) {
        degreeScheme = stuDegree;
    }

    //Print the student details
    public void printStudent() {
        System.out.println("Forname:" + forName);
        System.out.println("Surename:" + 
surName);
        System.out.println("Student ID:" + 
studentID);
        System.out.println("Degree Scheme:" + 
degreeScheme);
    }

    // setter
    public void setForName(String forName) {
        this.forName = forName;
    }

    // getter
    public String getForName() {
        return forName;
    }
}
```

I also wish to run this test file on my original code would the program written be suitable for testing?

```
import java.io.*;

public class StudentTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*create three new objects using constructor*/
    Student stuOne = new Student()
    Student stuTwo = new Student()
    Student stuThree = new Student()

    //Invoking Methods for Each object Created
    stuOne.forName("James")
    stuOne.stuSurname("Smith")
    stuOne.stuID("0987")
    stuOne.stuDegree("Computer Science")

    stuTwo.forName("Vanessa")
    stuTwo.stuSurname("Peach")
    stuTwo.stuID("0988")
    stuTwo.stuDegree("Mathematics")

    stuThree.forName("George")
    stuThree.stuSurname("BlackSmith")
    stuThree.stuID("0989")
    stuThree.stuDegree("English")
   }
}
```

the tester much be able to create three instances of Student and print them out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Why Does This Happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228062/java-why-does-this-happen)

Comment: Aside: this isn't going to work: `public Student(String name) { this.forName = forName;` as the parameter is `name`, not `forName`. And there are missing semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in the `StudentTest` (like no semi-colons for endings), but the specific OP's question was about the `main` class.

The `Student` class has `main` defined as:

```
private static void main(String[] args) {
```

As the error states, the signature must be *public*, so changing to :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

will resolve that particular issue. There are, however, other issues elsewhere, such as the constructor:

```
   //This is the Constructor of the 
public Student(String name) {
    this.forName = forName;
}
```

As the parameter is `name`, this will need to be:

```
this.forName = name;
```

(or change the name of the parameter, either one).

Comment: this worked perfectly, could you take a look at the final snippet of code as this gives me many compile errors

Comment: @CanIBeHelped, you should post the specific compile errors you are seeing as a new question. Please do not combine multiple questions into a single SO post. However, as I noted, the `StudentTest` class currently does not have a single `;` to conclude the statements, so at a minimum that will need to be fixed.